# "Function was not implemented" when trying to use ONI recording

Tags: osx-lion, kinect, playback, recording, openni

I'm trying to use an `oni` recording in my application using OpenNI. Here is my `xml` file:

```
<OpenNI>
    <Licenses>
        <!-- Add application-specific licenses here 
        <License vendor="vendor" key="key"/>
        -->
    </Licenses>
    <Log writeToConsole="false" writeToFile="false">
        <!-- 0 - Verbose, 1 - Info, 2 - Warning, 3 - Error (default) -->
        <LogLevel value="3"/>
        <Masks>
            <Mask name="ALL" on="true"/>
        </Masks>
        <Dumps>
        </Dumps>
    </Log>
    <ProductionNodes>
        <Recording file="Recording.oni" />

        <!-- Set global mirror -->
        <GlobalMirror on="true"/>

    </ProductionNodes>
</OpenNI>
```

Everything looks ok, but when I try to run my program, I get:

```
Open failed: Function was not implemented!
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem were the two following lines:

```
    <!-- Set global mirror -->
    <GlobalMirror on="true"/>
```

After removing them, my program works fine.